# First knockout js drop down list

Tags: knockout.js

I am just started working on knock out js today!!

Please can anybody give any live example of binding knock out js drop down list. I referred the example in knock out js but i could not bind it to drop down!!

```
<div id="state_container">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="form" 
        data-bind="with:" width="300px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>StateName&nbsp; </span>

                &nbsp;<input type="text" name="stateName" data-bind="value:CountryName" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Short Name</span>


                <input type="text" name="shortname" data-bind="value:ShortName" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Country&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>&nbsp;
                  <select   data-bind="options:availableCountries,optionsCaption: 'Select Date'" style="width: 148px">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Add" data-bind="click:$parent.Submit" />


                <input type="button" name="btnReset" value="Reset" data-bind="click:$parent.Reset" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var viewmodel = { availableCountries: ko.observableArray(['India', 'Austaralia']) };

</script>
```

What more i am missing here?? please give me any refernces which explains knock out js binding!!

Comment: This might be a really good start for you: [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) And don't just read the introduction, at the least you should read about everything all the way up to the Binding Syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually binding the model?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewmodel = { availableCountries: ko.observableArray(['India', 'Austaralia']) };
    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
</script>
```

Another thing I noticed: You have a half-written binding in your table:

```
data-bind="with:"
```

That will probably break things regardlessly.

Comment: I removed that half written bindings,, atleast that caption is also not getting shown..Is there any any problem with content place holders?? I am using masterpage and i placed all my jquery lib, knock out js lib in master page itselft